# z-index issue when using bootstrap-select with input-group and form-control classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, z-index, bootstrap-select

#### My code

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) plugin.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
        </span>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option value="1" text="Test"></option>
            <option value="2" text="Test 2"></option>
            <option value="3" text="Test 3"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
        <input type="email" required class="form-control" placeholder="Email Adress"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/</span>
        <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="ID">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Result

When closed:
[image: dropdown closed]

When open:
[image: dropdown open]

#### Possible reason

bootstrap-select plugin generates the following HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown bootstrap-select form-control open">...</div>
```

Bootstrap CCS has the following rule which aligns all `form-control`'s inside `.input-group` at the same `z-index`:

```css
.input-group .form-control {
    z-index: 2;
    // ...
}
```

#### Question

I want items in the dropdown to appear in front of the input fields, but they are rendered behind (see the above screenshots). Browser: Chrome 71.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct HTML should be

```
<div class="dropdown bootstrap-select input-group-btn form-control open">...</div>
```

The bootstrap-select plugin should have generated this class for you, but if it hasn't - just append the class manually. Example:

```
<select class="form-control input-group-btn selectpicker">
```

#### Result

[image: dropdown open]

#### Explanation

The bootstrap-select plugin has the following CCS rule which does the trick:

```css
.bootstrap-select.form-control.input-group-btn {
    z-index: auto;
}
```